# VSCode - Display an image while debugging

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am currently using visual studio code to debug a python file. In that python file is a numpy image. When i try to import matplotlib to display the image, it doesn't show:

```
- plt.imshow(pred_scores)
<matplotlib.image.AxesImage object at 0x7f3d43e691d0>
- plt.show()
None
- pred_scores
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
...
```

Basically nothing happens. Is it actually possible to show an image here?

Comment: Show where? Is this in the debug console? What do the dashes in your code example represent?

Comment: my issue is with xserver:
https://superuser.com/questions/1560976/cant-get-xserver-ubuntu-desktop-to-work-aws-workstation

Answer (score 11):

There's an extension allows you to view images/plots during python debugging. You simply select the image variable in the editor, and click on the light bulb will appear near it. Basically, it just save the image into a temporary location, and open it on the side.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the extension.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=elazarcoh.simply-view-image-for-python-debugging

Comment: let me try this!

Comment: Thank you so much!. I needed this extension badly.

Answer (score 4):

You could use VS Code Jupyter Interactive Windows to render your plots.

At the entry script of your solution code base (e.g. `main.py`), either start a debugging session in Interactive Window (`> Jupyter: Debug Current File in Interactive Window`) from the command palette, or, as I prefer, add `#%%` at the first line and click `Debug Cell`.

[image]

You can now interactively render your plots during a VS Code debugging session, regardless of whether it is locally or remotely

[image]

There is a discussion about this on GitHub

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1278

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any way of actually showing the image, but for debugging purposes, you could always just save it to a file using  [matplotlib.pyplot.savefig](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html):

```
plt.savefig('debug.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just use this method.

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2

def showImage(img):

    def show(img):
        cv2.imshow(str(dt.datetime.today()), img)
        cv2.waitKey()

    Thread(target=show, args=[img]).start()
```